# Why does UIImageView remove when I used removeFromSuperview()?

Tags: swift, uiimageview

Why does UIImageView remove from Array when I used removeFromSuperview() with Swift?

```
// display UIImageView
var imageViews: [UIImageView] = [UIImageView]()
imageViews.append(UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "test.jpg")))
let imageView = imageViews[0]
self.view.addSubview(imageView) // display image view

let overlayView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
overlayView.addSubview(imageView)
self.view.addSubview(overlayView)
overlayView.removeFromSuperview()

// not display image view
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Are you sure this is the entire code?

Comment: Your issue can not be represented in standard environment. We need more information, maybe about multi-threads you using

Comment: sorry, I was wrong. I changed the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `imageView` to `overlayView`. Later on you are removing `overlayView` from superview.

When you remove a view (`removeFromSuperview`:) a release is performed on the view and its subviews. Thus your `imageView` is removed. Check the official [documentation reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622421-removefromsuperview) on `removeFromSuperview`.

Comment: So I did like this. but it will not display.    
    
`let overlayView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
let tmpImageView = self.headerImageViews[self.pageControl.currentPage]
let currentImageView = self.headerImageViews[self.pageControl.currentPage]
overlayView.addSubview(currentImageView)
self.view.addSubview(overlayView)
overlayView.removeFromSuperview()
self.headerImageViews[self.pageControl.currentPage] = tmpImageView // empty`

Answer (score 0):

When you add your `imageView` to `overlayView` and subsequently remove `overlayView` from its super view, this will also remove any subviews of `overlayView` including your `imageView`. Therefore it will not display.

Comment: i know. but, i added imageview into self.view directly at firstly. so, it's not subview of overlayview.